# use NSScanner to parse string

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, string-parsing, nsscanner

The two-line string to parse is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2772] (rev 02)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2776] (rev 02)
```

to get these strings out:

(from 1st line)

- VGA compatible controller
- Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
- [8086:2772]

(from 2nd line)

- Display controller
- Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller
- [8086:2776]

Now my starting code is:

```
NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:strtoparse];
NSString *devtype;      
while ([scn isAtEnd] == NO)
    {
       if( [scn scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] intoString:NULL] &&
        [scn scanUpToString:@"[" intoString:&devtype]);
    }
```

and this aint working. I cant even understand the scanner from the docs. So can someone post working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick snippet:

```
NSString *theString = @"00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2772] (rev 02)\n00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2776] (rev 02)";

NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:theString];

NSCharacterSet *space = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
NSCharacterSet *bracket = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"["];
NSCharacterSet *linebreak = [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet];

NSString *type;
NSString *name;
NSString *number;

while (![theScanner isAtEnd]) 
{
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:space intoString:nil] ;
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:bracket intoString:&type]; 
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:space intoString:nil] ;
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:bracket intoString:&name]; 
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:space intoString:&number]; 
    [theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:linebreak intoString:nil] ;

    NSLog(type);
    NSLog(name);
    NSLog(number);
}
```

Output:

```
VGA compatible controller 
Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller 
[8086:2772]
Display controller 
Intel Corporation 82945G/GZ Integrated Graphics Controller 
[8086:2776]
```